# Replace ASCII Control Characters with Unicode Symbols for Control Characters

Tags: java, android, unicode, character-encoding

I'm looking for a fast an easy way to replace Ascii control characters with the appropriate unicode symbols for those characters for logging purposes.

Examples:

- ASCII → Desired Output
- 0x00 → ␀ (U+2400)
- 0x01 → ␁ (U+2401)
- 0x02 → ␂ (U+2402)
- 0x1F → ␟ (U+241F)

My input is a byte array with known length. I currently use `new String(byData, 0, nLength, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII).replaceAll("\\W", "�");` but that is removing useful information like carriage returns (␍).

I know I could manually do a find and replace for each of the 32 control characters but I figure there has got to be a better and faster way.

My project has Guava installed so if there is some Guava magic for this, let me know.

I'm using Java 7/Android.

Answer (score 1):

A manual loop is probably your best bet:

```
String s = new String(byData, 0, nLength, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    int ch = (int) sb.charAt(i);
    if ((cp < 32) && (ch != 9) && (ch != 10) && (ch != 13)) {
        sb.setCharAt(i, (char)(0x2400 + ch));
    }
}

s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This worked great. Would you mind if i edited your code to match the exact utility method I ended up writing?